# Fails ST_intersects(geom, select statement) for drive time

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, spatial-join, routing, st-intersects

I am trying to select houses in a drive time isochrone.
I have the code working fine to make the isochrone.
I can't place the results in a seperate table
I need the isochrone in a where clause

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Here is where i get to:

```
SELECT "uk_properties"."id" AS "id",
  "uk_properties"."geom" AS "geom",
  "uk_properties"."address" AS "address",
  "uk_properties"."type" AS "type"
FROM "public"."uk_properties" AS "uk_properties"
where ST_Contains(
      SELECT cast(ST_convexhull(ST_collect(tableauways.the_geom))
        as geometry(Polygon,4326)) from tableauways join (
SELECT * from pgr_drivingDistance(
        'SELECT gid as id
        , source
        , target
        , length_m/(26.82*10) AS cost from tableauways'
        , (select source from tableauways
                    order by tableauways.the_geom <-> 
                        (
                        select geom from asda_items
                        where storedesc = 'ISLE OF DOGS'
                        limit 1)
            limit 1),
                10,FALSE)
) as route on tableauways.target = route.node

, "uk_properties"."geom")
```

The first half of the st_contains (the isochrone generating bit) works perfectly on its own and returns a single geom.

Any ideas why I get:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 14:   SELECT cast(ST_convexhull(ST_collect(tableauways.the_geom)...

Comment: You might need to escape the apostophes around 'isle of dogs'? (double up the apostrophes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the result of a query within a function call, it must be enclosed in parentheses:

```
--geometry vs "select geometry" --> fail
select ST_Contains('point(0 0)',select 'point(0 0)');
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 1: select ST_Contains('point(0 0)',select 'point(0 0)');
                                        ^
--geometry vs "(select geometry)" --> success
select ST_Contains('point(0 0)',(select 'point(0 0)'));
 st_contains
-------------
 t
(1 row)
```